# Progress Openedge syntax to read array data from url back into temp-table

Tags: progress-4gl

i suspect the answer to this will be laughably simple, but i am new to this, and cant find anything on the forms. In a small webhandler class, i have written a handleget procedure that, when called using the relevant http address, via web or postman returns an array of data from our database.

```
 METHOD OVERRIDE PROTECTED INTEGER HandleGet (poRequest AS OpenEdge.Web.IWebRequest):

        DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse AS WebResponse NO-UNDO .
        DEFINE VARIABLE oJson     AS JsonObject  NO-UNDO .
        DEFINE VARIABLE oArray    AS JsonArray   NO-UNDO .

        DEFINE VARIABLE oUsers    AS JsonObject  NO-UNDO .
        DEFINE VARIABLE oError    AS JsonObject  NO-UNDO .



        ASSIGN
            oResponse             = NEW WebResponse ()
            /* HTTP messages require a content type */
            oResponse:ContentType = 'application/json':U

         cQryString               = poRequest:GetPathParameter("WhoIsThere"). 


        /* cQryString = STRING(poRequest:GetContextValue("QUERY_STRING")). */

        oJson = NEW JsonObject () .

        GetUserandPass ().


        oJson:Add("name", cName) .
        oJson:Add("password", cPassword) . 

        custLkUp ().

        oUsers = NEW JsonObject () .

        oUsers:Read (TEMP-TABLE ttUser:HANDLE, TRUE /*omitInitlVals*/, FALSE /*readBeforeImage*/) .
        oJson:Add ("users", oUsers:GetJsonArray("ttUser")) .


        oResponse:Entity = oJson .
```

using the post facility on postman, i have altered some of the data, with the wish that, on send, the array, complete with altered data is posted back to my code where the changes can be applied to the database. the file/array structure will not change in anyway, but there will be delays between sending the data to the url and the post back. i am trying to do this in a handlepost procedure.
How do i capture the changed array,

have tried

```
oJson = CAST(poRequest:entity,JsonObject)
buffer ttUserupd:READ-JSON("json object", oJson, "empty").
```

to read it into identical temptable structure but keeps saying invalid handle in the agentlog.
what have i missed?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to send back the changed records? If so, you can call the `GET-CHANGES()`  method. This requires the temp-table to have a before table defined, and to be part of a dataset, and `TRACKING-CHANGES` turned on before making any changes to the data.